# Ошибка Unreachable statement в DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

Создаю фрагмент диалог, ввожу в `onCreateView` данные из `View`, но данные не принимаются, а подчёркиваются красным цветом.
Вот код:

```
public class Fragment_Dialog_Coast extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public double summa;
public String nameCoast;
public String description;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View view  = inflater.inflate (R.layout.layout_dialod,container,false);

    return view;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return super.onCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

явно лишнее, все что ниже не выполнится